# Haproxy acl based on URL param existence

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to route requests to different backends based on the existence of an URL param. I tried the following, but it never matches, even if my request contains a `host` param, e.g. `POST http://127.0.0.1/result?build=2021041601&host=foo123`:

```
acl has_host_urlparam urlp(host)
use_backend backend-host if has_host_urlparam
default_backend backend-generic
```

Do I have to compare the value returned from urlp() with something to check for existence of the param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, I was missing a flag to look for match existence:

```
acl has_host_urlparam urlp(host) -m found
use_backend backend-host if has_host_urlparam
default_backend backend-generic
```